# Make a very long switch statement more readable

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have written a switch statement with over 11 cases like the following...

```
switch (x)
{
    case x = 0:
        x = x + 1;
    break;
    case x = 1:
        x = x + 2;
    break;
    // and so one...
}
```

The problem is I find by writing the code in this way it looks quite **ugly** and it's **hard to maintain**, is there's another way of **formatting it to be more readable**?

(NOTE: If the question is not on topic or has something wrong please, tell me what is it before downvoting/reporting it)

Comment: That's not currently valid code. Could you give a [mcve], and give us more context? Do all the cases effectively end up doubling x and adding 1? The more realistic the example is, the more likely we are to be able to help you.

Comment: The only thing i can suggest is worry about other things, and get used to how switch looks. There are bigger fish that need to be fried

Comment: don't put `x=` in the case. Make it just `case 0:`. This looks like it can just be reduced to `x=x+x+1` or `x+=x+1` or `x=x*2+1`. This is on topic at the code review stack exchange

Comment: In a lot of cases switch can be replaced by some sort of algorithm or polymorphism. Currently this can be simplified to a simple addition function. If you can't remove the switch statement altogether, then the best you can do, is to just bury it into a separate class, give descriptive name to a method that contains the switch and leave it be.

Comment: Okay, @pinkfloydx33 that's a good tip.

Comment: Also, I might look into what @Krypt1 said and try and see what can I do, thanks for all of you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code does not compile, I think you meant:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 0:
        x = x + 1;
    break;
    case 1:
        x = x + 2;
    break;
}
```

This is just my own wild guess, but the rest of the switch statement probably looks like this:

```
case 2:
    x = x + 3;
break;
case 3:
    x = x + 4;
break;
case 4:
    x = x + 5;
break;
```

You can simplify the whole thing to this:

```
x += x + 1
```

If I guessed wrongly, you can still try to simplify this by using a dictionary. Here is an example:

```
// It could also be a Dictionary<int, Func<int, int>> or some other delegate
// if you want to compute the value from "x" or execute some random code
Dictionary<int, int> xDict = new Dictionary<int, int> {
    {0, <some value you want x to be>},
    {1, <some value you want x to be>},
    //...
}

x = xDict[x];
```

Comment: What I wrote above was just an example and yep sorry, I have mistaken, since I'm writing in notepad++

Comment: @AbdelfatahRadwan How do you find the dictionary approach. Does it work for your actual problem?

Comment: probably you want to have some `Func<int,int>` as dictionary value to be more generic like `{0, x=>x+1}`

Comment: @DmitryPavliv I was thinking of doing that but because OP didn't show what their code actually is like, I made it simpler. Now I added a note about that.